# Error: Cannot convert from 'Intranet.Models.LoanModification to Intranet.Models.Loan

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting a message: Error: Cannot convert from 'Intranet.Models.LoanOrderModification to Intranet.Models.LoanOrder on the line db.LoanOrders.Add(newLoan); from the code below. I created a new model in the class LoanOrders which I named LoanOrderModification , this class also has LoanOrder. What am I missing where the controller is looking for LoanOrder model and not LoanOrderModification model?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateModifiedLoanOrder(LoanOrderModification newLoanOrder, string submit)
{

try
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.LoanOrders.Add(newLoanOrder);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("LoanOrders");
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
    }

    return View();
```

}

Model:

```
    namespace Intranet.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public partial class LoanOrder
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Branch { get; set; }


    public partial class LoanOrderModification
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Purpose { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: newLoanOrder is `LoanOrderModification`, I assume you probably have `db.LoanOrderModifications` you should be adding to instead of db.LoadOrders, cant tell without more details.

Comment: `db.LoanOrders.Add(newLoanOrder);` should be `db.LoanOrderModification.Add(newLoanOrder);`

Comment: The 2 classes both update the same Database - db.loanorders. The only difference is 1 of the classes I am not requiring a few strings. A Question I would have is what tells the views . controller  what class to use if there are multiple classes in a model?